# How is Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml used?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

I am looking to implement single sign on functionality into an existing Asp.Net MVC 5 web application using SAML 2.0. My team and I have looked into a few different NuGet packages to help us get started with this implementation. We already have the IdP and metadata file, but now just need to implement  the SSO functionality into our project.

We came across the Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml package and were interested in using this to set up our SAML configuration but have not been able to find any documentation on how this is actually implemented. I was wondering what is this package typically used for and can it be used to handle SAML requests and responses for the implementation of SSO functionality into a web application or should we look into using a different package? Thanks!

Comment: [I need a SAML stack](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43)

Answer (score 1):

This package is for handling SAML assertion security tokens. It's not for handling the SAML SSO protocol. The WS-Trust protocol supports a number of different security token types including SAML assertions. The Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml package provides this support. SAML SSO also uses SAML assertions but is a completely different protocol from WS-Trust.

You'll find there are a number of open source implementations of the SAML v2.0 specification as well as our commercial offering.